# How to bring a dragable div to front when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I would like to bring a jQuery dragable div to the front when clicked. I read [this post](http://%3Cdiv%20class=%22front-on-click%22%3ETwo%3Cbr%3Eis%20higher%3C/div%3E), and build the JsFiddle here, but it did not work. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Here is the jsfiddle I created, the elements are dragable and will be brought to front while dragging, but i could not bring them to front while just being clicked. Is there a conflict between z-index?
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liusashmily/hugnffzh/1/)

Here is the code:
HTML

```
<div>
<div id="box1" class="front-on-click"></div>
<div id="box2" class="front-on-click"></div>
<div id="box3" class="front-on-click"></div>
<div id="box4" class="front-on-click"></div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#box1,#box2,#box3,#box4').draggable({stack: "div"});
$('.front-on-click').click(function(){
   $('.front').removeClass('front');
   $(this).addClass('front');
});

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I could drag them and put it on front, can you be more clear on what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes....drag and put it front is working....i want to just click and put it in front as well.....

Comment: you mean when you click on div it come front of all div

Comment: yes! sorry i did not describe it well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the reason why it won't work, but I got it working by changing your code with the following-

```
$('.front-on-click').click(function() {
    $('.front').css('z-index','0').removeClass('front');
    $(this).addClass('front').css('z-index','100');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 $('.front-on-click').click(function(){
    $(".front-on-click").each(function(){
        $(this).css("z-index", "1");
        $(this).removeClass('front');
    });
    $(this).css("z-index", "10");
    $(this).addClass('front');
});
```

Comment: this works as well, but Abhishek's answer is simpler. Thank you all the same!